# Know my mail sending options

Tags: mail, gmail, sendmail

I am having a ubuntu server with 12.04. How I detect which mail server I am using.
I can't find any listed mail servers `POSTFIX`, `SENDMAIL` etc..
Is there any settings related to gmail SMTP?

Answer (score 0):

If there is a SMTP server running on your system, first look up its process id:
`sudo fuser -4uv -n tcp 25` 
(assuming it is listening to port 25) If this remains blank, there is no SMTP server. If there is, use 
`ps -ef | grep <PID>`
 to find its command line. Replace `<PID>` with the process id you found with the `fuser` command.